# Docker Swarm service entry will not be removed even if service creation failed?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I want to confirm one thing about docker swarm service.

If the service is not created successfully, for example, the container of that service is failed to be started due to some reasons, the REPLICAS will always be 0/1? And this service entry will not be removed from service list even if when the setting of --restart-max-attempts=1?

Is there anyway could let the service entry removed from service list once service creation is failed?

Thanks for any help!